# I am trying to set up Chrome driver

Tags: java, selenium-chromedriver

IDE output: “This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 114
Current browser version is 116.”

Any guess how to fix it?

Help would me much appreciated!

org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 114
Current browser version is 116.0.5845.96 with binary path /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

Comment: Uh, maybe update your ChromeDriver to match your browser?  Or downgrade your browser to make your ChromeDriver.

Comment: Counterpoint: if you're still trying to set things up, forget about chrome driver (or webdriver in general) and start using [Playwright](https://playwright.dev/), which talks to browsers through their dev tools protocol, and "just works(tm)".

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it by updating the WebDriverManager to the newest version.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
  <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
  <version>5.5.3</version>
</dependency>
```

The download location for the ChromeDriver has been changed. The old download URL supports Chrome versions up to 114.

https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE

Newer versions must be downloaded from another location.

https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing